# Variables outside of #each with handlbars

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

I have the data,

```
data = {
  "items":  [
      {"value": "New", "id": 1},
      {"value": "Open", "id": 2},
      {"value": "Close", "id": 3}
    ],
  "current": 2
}
```

I'm my template I loop through items, but want to access the current value while in the loop.

This doesn't work,

```
{{#each items}}
    {{id}} - {{value}} - {{current}} 
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://handlebarsjs.com/#paths):

> Nested handlebars paths can also include `../` segments, which evaluate their paths against a parent context.

So you want to use `{{../current}}` to access the value of `current` in the parent context.

Demo: http://jsbin.com/iyofuq/1/edit