# Handlebarsjs change each helper context

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, handlebars.js

I have a nested each helper inside an each helper. i want to accsess a variable from the outer each helper inside the inner each helper. code bellow

```
{{#each this=outer}}
    <li>
    {{each this.values}}
        <input type='radio' value='{{this}}' data-id='{{outer.id}}'>
    {{/each}}
    </li>
{{/each}}
```

the above syntax does not work

Comment: possible duplicate of [Variables outside of #each with handlbars](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13284141/variables-outside-of-each-with-handlbars)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a parent context using `../` inside the variable.

I'm not sure how your data is structured but your template should probably look something like this:

```
{{#each outer}}
    <li>
    {{each outer.values}}
        <input type='radio' value='{{this}}' data-id='{{../outer.id}}'>
    {{/each}}
    </li>
{{/each}}
```

[Check out this github issue for more.](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/issues/183)